# invalid model formula in ExtractVars Error

Tags: r

Trying to input a model in R and keep getting the same error

This is the model:

```
modelo1=lm(Chou~(0.1438+0.2051*DAP*pespecifico-(0.0744*((DAP-50)*v.dicotomica)))^2.5, data=Parcela_1)
```

This is the error

> Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) :
> invalid model formula in ExtractVars

Comment: `lm()`  is used to *estimate* model parameters, not apply pre-existing ones. Just create a custom function that takes the predictor variables as inputs, and return the outcome.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg